# Android using custom number keypad, how to create a delete key?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a number key pad that I created, it is entering text into a EditText box, I have that working but dont know how to code the delete button. I need it to delete one char at a time.

Here is a code sample:

```
public class QOQuickOrder extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private final String MY_DATABASE_NAME = "/sdcard/hdw";

private EditText qoItemNumber;
private EditText qoOrderQty;
private TextView qoItemDesc;

Cursor c;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.qo_quickorder_layout);

    qoItemNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etqoItemNumEntry);
    qoOrderQty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etqoItemQtyEntry);
    qoItemDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvqoItemDesc);

    qoItemNumber.selectAll();
    qoItemNumber.setText("");

    Button oneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button twoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button threeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button fourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button fiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button sixButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button sevenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button eightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button nineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button zeroButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);

    oneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    twoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    threeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    fourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    fiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    sixButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    sevenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    eightButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    nineButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    zeroButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    qoItemNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus = true){

                getItemDesc();
            }

        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View v){


    qoItemNumber.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));



}
```

Comment: If you know how to add text to a string, removing it isn't all that different...

Comment: I can remove the entire string but want to remove one number per click, I dont know how to do that.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29 It's a STRING... use string operations...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following method to delete your edit text last characters one at a time :

```
String str = youredittext.getText().toString().trim();
if(str.length()!=0){
str  = str.substring( 0, str.length() - 1 ); 
youredittext.setText ( str );
```

Let me know if you have any queries regarding the same.